# Placeholder behaviour incl. custom color for select - is this really impossible?

Tags: jquery, select, colors, placeholder

What I try to achieve is the placeholder behaviour available for text inputs and textareas: the placeholder has a different color, and if the user inputs a value, and then removes it, both the placeholder value and the placeholder color gets reset.

The specific case: we have a select item with a so-called placeholder option where this option's text is 'Select Treatment' and the option's value is empty. I'd like to make the select element behave the following way:

1. ON DOCUMENT READY: the selected option is the placeholder option and the color is the placeholder color;
2. ON SELECT MOUSEDOWN ( or CLICK ) both select and option color changes to default -  and it remains the default color if the selected option is not the placeholder option;
3. IF THE PLACEHOLDER OPTION IS RE-SELECTED, the color changes again to the placeholder color.

Now, as far as I see, this just can't be achieved. I tried to bind the appropriate color changes to mousedown, click and change events, in all imaginable variations, but the thing, in the end, doesn't work. What happens is:

1. On DOCUMENT READY the thing works: select color is the placeholder color.
2. On FIRST SELECT MOUSEDOWN the thing works, everything changes into the default color.
3. On SELECTING A VALUE ELSE THAN THE PLACEHOLDER the thing works, color remains the default color.
4. On RE-ESELECTING THE PLACEHOLDER the thing works - color resets to placeholder color.

AND THEN BOOM -> 5. on another SELECT MOUSEDOWN the color doesn't change to the default color.

The code I tried, at least one of the variations, was ( optionvals.color_sec being the variable holding the default color ):

```
// Select field type color manipulation
$('.noosa-contact-form select').css('color', '#ccc');

$('.noosa-contact-form select').on( 'change', function() {

    $this = $(this);

    if ( $this.val() == '' )
        $(this).css('color', '#ccc');
    else {
        $this.css('color', optionvals.color_sec);
    }

} )
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippet to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve and the issue that you are describing? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure, it's available now at https://jsfiddle.net/jpsafgqz/6/

So, you can see here that the color of the selected value doesn't change the way it "should have" in a friendly placeholder case. It doesn't change into green on mousedown, and the selected option, again, is not green. That's what I tried/try to achieve, but I have bad feelings about how possible this really is.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally it came out it's possible. Happy day!!
The desired effect can be achieved by involving both `select` and `option` in the styling à la jquery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('select').css('color', '#ccc');
    $('option[value=""]').addClass('placeholder');

    $('select').on('mousedown', function() {

        $('option:not(.placeholder)', this).css('color', '#db0a5b');
        $('.placeholder', this).css('color', '#ccc');

    })

    $('select').on('change', function() {

        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('color', '#ccc');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', '#db0a5b');
        }

    })

})
```

The working example can be seen at https://jsfiddle.net/jpsafgqz/17/

Thanks for guest271314 for pointing me in the right direction.